# How to get diff for specified user between two dates from git?

Tags: git, date, diff

How to get `diff` for specified user between two dates from git? Or, how to use git `whatchanged` command to list commits for specified user?

Is there any none-scripting way (builtin git command)?

Answer (score 36):

I believe there's no such a way to get a diff only knowing dates.

As of today you can do the following:

```
git log --since "OCT 4 2011" --until "OCT 11 2011" --pretty=format:"%H"
```

And then `git diff` between first and last revisions. If the revision list is far too long, use the above `git log ...` with `| head -1` and `| tail -1` to get the first and the last revisions.

Note that the above git log will return revisions **exactly** between given dates, i.e. revisions for OCT 5, OCT 6, ..., OCT 10.

Comment: You can _sort_ of do it directly with diff, but not so reliably, using the `@{date}` notation, e.g., `git diff @{date1} @{date2}`.

The problem with that is that the `@{date}` construct doesn't look at the commit history to translate the date into a commit-id, but instead uses the _revlog_.  The result is that if you pull _really often_, your revlog will have fine-grained enough info that the above may do what you want, but if you _don't_, the results will be inaccurate...

Comment: I had to add equal sign to make it work:
```git log --since="FEB 1 2014" --until="FEB 30 2014"```

Answer (score 4):

This is possible, and with the user / committer criteria:

```
git log --after="2015-10-14" --before="2015-10-21" --grep="MB[FT][0-9-]*" --author="John\|Mary"
```

This will match anything

- between those date
- by authors matching the names `John` **or** `Mary`
- where the commit message includes (e.g. a Jira ticket number in the form of) `MBT` or `MBF` plus a number-code that can include a `-` char.

Comment: This displays the log, but not a diff.

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --since "MAY 1 2017" --until "MAY 31 2017" -p --author="Jack" > diffJackMay.patch
```